# Cannot match pagination URLs in Sinatra/Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I'm trying to match these valid urls:

```
/match/<searchterm>
/match/<searchterm>/page/<number>
```

`<searchterm>` are words that can possibly include spaces and `&`. It should NOT end with trailing space character(s).

Some valid examples:

```
/match/Hello
/match/Hello There
/match/Hello There & Bye
/match/Hello & Good Bye
/match/Hello There Lots of & words here

/match/Hello/page/1
/match/Hello There/page/10
/match/Hello There & Bye/page/33
```

... and so on

These are invalid examples:

```
/match/Hello!
/match/Hello *
/match/Hello/page
/match/Hello /page/1
/match/Hello There    /page/1
```

I have tried several regexes, and this one seems close ([according to Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/jqb5wtOLjw)):

```
\/match\/([[\w]+[\s&]*]+)(\/page\/(\d+))*
```

But it does weird things like successfully matching:

```
/match/Hello ! There           /page/1
```

Furthermore, when I try this in my sinatra app, the Rubular regex doesn't even work at all:

```
get %r{\/match\/([[\w]+[\s&]*]+)(\/page\/(\d+))*} do
   puts 'Matched'
end
```

ie, 
Sinatra will fail to find this url when Rubular says it won't:

```
/match/Hello & There/page/1
```

What would be the proper regex for this problem? And why do regexes in Rubular work but not in Sinatra (as shown in the example)?

**EDIT:** I think the the spaces in the url explains why Sinatra isn't matching a valid regex. The url given to Sinatra comes back as:

```
/match/Hello%20&%20There
```

Where the whitespaces aren't actually whitespaces.

**EDIT 2:** Avinash Raj's regex is working fine, but I had to replace `\s` with `%20` because of the space issue in the url.

**New QUESTION:** Is replacing `\s` with `%20` a valid fix for this? Or is there a proper way for Sinatra to handle whitespaces in the url? I don't see any info on it in the documentation:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include start and end anchors in your pattern to do an exact line match.

```
^\/match\/(\w(?:[\w&\s]|%20)*\w)(?:\/page\/(\d+))*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/11)

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/P8AwuH6BL3)

Comment: I tried that in Sinatra, and Sinatra fails match it:

`get %r{^\/match/(\w[\w&\s]*\w)(?:\/page\/(\d+))*$} do`

fails on something like:  `/match/Hello & There`.

Comment: Your regex seems to be correct. I think the issue is with the whitespaces in the URL (see edit). Would a valid solution be to look for `%20` instead of `\s`?

Comment: @user21398 updated for the links which contains spaces or `%20`. It would match both type of links..